# How can I use partial server projects in my server project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

#### Scenario:

In my organisation, we separately develop multiple applications. In the end however, many of the applications (and their databases) are deployed to the same SQL instance, so they share the same master database.

We use Visual Studio 2010 database and server projects to source control said databases.

To try and standardise some things, I want to do the following:

1. Create a 'Core' Server database project which has all the server settings, core logins etc. Things like SET TRUSTWORTHY ON and server-level ANSI settings etc.
2. Have each Application's own Server.dbproj specify the logins and roles etc specific to that application.
3. Have each Application's own ApplicationDatabase.dbproj reference the ApplicationX.Server.dbproj

In theory, each Application in source control would only contain the items specific to it, rather than keeping server related settings or configuration synchronised across many projects.

#### Problem

However, in practice I can get this far:

1. Done. Produces a .schema file which I reference in future steps
2. Done. Server.dbproj happily references Core.dbschema and 'extends' it with it's own logins and roles etc. Is happy to deploy this anywhere I point it.
3. Nadda. I add a reference from ApplicationDatabase.dbproj to Server.dbproj (assuming Server would pull in the items from Core) and it complains about any logins that are actually in Core.

So I then added both Server and Core as references to ApplicationDatabase as it settled down. Compiles fine.

However, when you deploy, you get the same problem described here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/vstsdb/thread/23cb9132-00d4-42ed-b34c-ab49027cddf7

```
Error TSD01234: The source model contains 2 server option elements. 
Only one element can be   contained in a model that can be deployed
```

The problem I think is that ApplicationDatabase essentially has two Server projects that it knows about, and therefore duplicate settings.

Microsofts documentation makes no mention of using partial projects in Server projects, but neither is it listed as a limitation.

#### So the question is...

Has anybody used partial projects successfully for Server projects, or is there a way you can see to achieve the same thing?

I'll be honest and say I won't just 'remove the Server projects' to make the problem disappear - we had it working very well up until I tried to improve things!